# Teams Bot OAuthPrompt Not returning Tokenresponse for a couple of company members

Tags: c#, botframework, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I have made and implemented a Teams bot for my company that is connected to a ASP.NET program on Azure but I am having some problems using the `OAuthPrompt`.

To give you some context and application insight: The endpoint is a BotController that allows Anonymous requests on `/api/messages`, this then uses the `IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter` and `IBot` to handle the request. My adapter is using `base.Use(new TeamsSSOTokenExchangeMiddleware)` to get SSO to work. In the `IBot` I override the method `OnMessageActivityAsync` to process incomming request. I first check if the user is trying to log out (mainly testing debugging purposes) and if not logout it tries to get the userToken, if this returns a succes, I will process the message which is working. If `tokenResponse == null`, I start a dialog for the authentication. In here I register an `OAuthPrompt` and a `WaterfallDialog` to process the authentication.

The services:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<BotFrameworkAuthentication, ConfigurationBotFrameworkAuthentication>();
services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithErrorHandler>();
services.AddTransient<MainDialog>();
services.AddTransient<IBot, TeamsBot<MainDialog>>();
```

and the main dialog:

```cs
public MainDialog(IConfiguration configuration, IMemoryCache memoryCache, ITeamsService teamsService)
{
    _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    _teamsService = teamsService;
    _configuration = configuration;
    AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(
        nameof(OAuthPrompt),
        new OAuthPromptSettings
        {
            ConnectionName = configuration["ConnectionName"] ?? throw new ArgumentException("ConnectionName"),
            Text = "Please Sign In",
            Title = "Sign In",
            Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login (1000 * 60 * 5)
            EndOnInvalidMessage = true
        }));

    AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
    {
        PromptStepAsync,
        LoginStepAsync,
    }));

    // The initial child Dialog to run.
    InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
}

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Log.Information("PromptStepAsync() called.");
    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken);
}

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> LoginStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Get the token from the previous step. Note that we could also have gotten the
    // token directly from the prompt itself. There is an example of this in the next method.
    var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)stepContext.Result;
    String? question;
    _memoryCache.TryGetValue(stepContext.Context.Activity.From.Id, out question);
    if (tokenResponse == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"LoginStepAsync: tokenResponse is null, question={question ?? "question is leeg"}");
    } else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"LoginStepAsync: question={question ?? "question is leeg"}, fromId: {stepContext.Context.Activity.From.Id}, tokenResponse: {tokenResponse.ConnectionName} / {tokenResponse.ChannelId} / {tokenResponse.Expiration}, hasToken: {tokenResponse.Token != null}");
        Console.WriteLine($"LoginStepAsync: fromId={stepContext.Context.Activity.From.Id}");
        Console.WriteLine($"LoginStepAsync: tokenResponse.ConnectionName={tokenResponse.ConnectionName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"LoginStepAsync: tokenResponse.ChannelId={tokenResponse.ChannelId}");
        Console.WriteLine($"LoginStepAsync: tokenResponse.Expiration={tokenResponse.Expiration}");
        Console.WriteLine($"LoginStepAsync: hasToken={tokenResponse.Token != null}");
        Console.WriteLine($"LoginStepAsync: tokenResponse.Properties={tokenResponse.Properties?.ToString() ?? "null"}");
    }
    if (tokenResponse?.Token != null && question != null)
    {
        await _teamsService.ProcessTeamsMessageAsync(stepContext.Context, question, tokenResponse.Token, cancellationToken);
    }
    else
    {
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Stuur je vraag nogmaals aub."), cancellationToken);
        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken);
    }

    return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}
```

```cs
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var userTokenClient = turnContext.TurnState.Get<UserTokenClient>();

    if (turnContext.Activity.Text.Equals("logout"))
    {
        await userTokenClient.SignOutUserAsync(turnContext.Activity.From.Id, _connectionName, turnContext.Activity.ChannelId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("You have been signed out."), cancellationToken);
        return;
    }

    var tokenResponse = await userTokenClient.GetUserTokenAsync(turnContext.Activity.From.Id, _connectionName, turnContext.Activity.ChannelId, null, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (tokenResponse == null)
    {
        _memoryCache.Set(turnContext.Activity.From.Id, turnContext.Activity.Text, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        await _dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, _conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
        return;
    }

    await _teamsService.ProcessTeamsMessageAsync(turnContext, turnContext.Activity.Text, tokenResponse.Token, cancellationToken);
}
```

As you can see in the image, the user tries to logout, and when sending the next message it fails, when trying to send it again it keeps giving the message `Stuur je vraag nogmaals aub.` When trying this as another user, everything works fine and the message to resend the question never shows. I checked Entra ID and there are no specific groups that are different. When I send the person a direct connection link (the one provided in the azure bot configuration), it instantly shows the token without login.
[image]

Is there anything I am missing or doing wrong with the dialog stuff? Please let me know if you need any extra information!

Comment: Please refer this sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/6c30223e303880f4bee85b09b9ae6fb6e726b211/samples/bot-teams-authentication

Comment: Apearantly it had nothing to do with my code, the company members with the problem were on the old teams client which was causing problems. I don't know how Microsoft does it but how do they break things so much...

Comment: Jasper - Is it resolved now with Classic Teams only or with New Teams client?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft only working with the new Teams client, once the employee had sent a message with the new client - thus authenticating once and caching the key, they could also go back to the old client and get the token succesfully. So only the first time (when the authentication really happens), it doesn't work

Comment: Means it is working with New Teams client every time and failing in classic Teams for first time only?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft correct, the initial authentication fails in classic Teams, once the token has been communicated to the servers, its fine

Comment: Hello @JasperB - Kindly confirm if it's working in New Teams at initial time as well?

Comment: Hi @ChetanSharma-msft is does work in the new teams client - all the time - first time users and users who had problems